# What is the difference between "probably" and "possibly"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, adverbs

Recently I saw the movie "Pursuit of Happyness", which is actually quite good, and I noticed the actor (Will Smith) asking the difference between *probably* and *possibly* to his son. So I would like to have people's opinion on this question as I am still yet to find an answer myself.

Comment: I would look up a dictionary rather than asking people’s opinions.

Comment: I would say the difference between _probably_ and _possibly_ is the about the same as the difference between _may_ and _might_.

Comment: @Eldros: I'm not sure that's an accurate comparison, as neither "may" nor "might" indicate any particular probability. See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7/may-might-whats-the-right-context and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3785/should-as-past-of-shall-might-as-past-of-may.

Comment: I remember the difference between these two words from the movie "Pursuit of Hapiness", where the son asks his dad about the different between the two words.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably

- chances of happening are high (or at least not minuscule)

Possibly

- chances of happening are not zero

Comment: "How can this possibly be true?" doesn't exactly reflect a non-zero chance, so no, it's not the full definition of the word.

Comment: "How can this possible be true?" -> "How can there be a non zero chance of this being true?" I don't see a problem in that.

Comment: the problem is that "probably" means exactly the same: non-zero chance, and never particularly very high chance.

Comment: @mojuba Possibly doesn't imply any mathematical probability apart from non-zero. The chance can be high or low, it just can happen (therefore non-zero). On the other hand Probably implies certain not small chance. If you are probably going to win, then the chances of winning are definitely not small.

Comment: I'd say that if something is "probable", it's implied to be the single most likely outcome.  I agree that "possible" isn't necessarily implying any particular level of mathematical probability, although the tone of voice in which someone says "it's possible" can speak volumes about just HOW possible they perceive it to be.

Comment: @Hellion Yeah, I'd agree with that. In fact, I'm inclined to edit my answer.

Answer (score 10):

These terms can actually be defined in a reasonably precise way, although they're sometimes used with a bit of liberty.

Let P = probability of event occurring

**Probably** => 0.5 < P < 1

**Possibly** => 0 < P << 1 (at least, in everyday speech, though more strictly P could be anything up to 1)

It is evident that in some cases, there is overlap between the two terms.

Comment: conversely, impossible => P = 0 and improbable => P ~ 0 (nearly zero)

Answer (score 7):

To say that something is [probably](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/probably?show=0&t=1291315272) the case is to say that that case is [probable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/probable). To say that something is [possibly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/possibly) the case is to say that it is [possible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/possible). The two are quite distinct.

If something is probable, then it is likely to happen. The chances are not only more than zero; they're better than 50/50 (or at least, the chances are higher that it'll happen than that it won't — since in comparing probabilities, you could have multiple items which have chances better than 50/50 but have one of them which is more probable than the others). *Probably* indicates that the laws of probability say that it's more likely to happen than not to happen.

On the other hand, if something is possible, then it *can* happen. Whether it *will* or not is irrelevant. The chances are better than zero. It doesn't say *anything* about how probable it is. It could be that the chances are .000000001% or that they're 100%. By saying that something is possible, you're not really saying anything about probability. You're just saying that it *could* — at least theoretically — happen.

So, if you say *possibly*, then you're saying that something *could* be the case, whereas if you're saying *probably*, you're saying that not only *can* it be the case but that the chances are higher that it will happen than that it won't.

Comment: I have the same intuition on *probably*. Note the multiple outcomes case -- if there are 2 red balls, 1 green, 1 blue and 1 pink, you'll probably pick a red ball at random (it's not 50/50, but more likely than the alternatives).

Comment: This is a bit unclear.  Saying that the chances of something are better than 50/50 is exactly the same as saying that it's more likely than not.  Relatedly, @dbkk, I disagree with your intuition: in your example, you probably *won't* pick a red ball at random.

Comment: @Henry I see your point. Native speakers can have different intuitions about word usage (or even syntax), especially for the edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

**Probably** implies that the probability of an event is higher than that of the alternatives. In the most common case with 2 alternatives, **probably** means something is more likely to happen than not. With 5 alternatives, probability of the event is >20%.

**Possibly** implies a non-zero probability, usually a low one.

Conversational usage may not fit neatly into these definitions, as the intent is often mild exaggeration or irony.

Comment: I guess I said this in response to your comment above, but I don't agree with your definition of probable.  Probable means more likely than not; two mutually contradictory possibilites cannot both be probable.  With 5 alternatives, no individual outcome is probable.

Answer (score 1):

Usage of Probably:

> Probably, you should be able to do it. = Mostly, you should be able to do it.

Usage of Possibly:

> Possibly, you should be able to do it. [= If there is a chance (some factor implied), you should be able to do it.]

> Possibly, you should be able to do it. [= If it is possible, you should be able to do it.]

Answer (score 0):

Wow... after reading the mumbo jumbo... hahaha I can't remember where I got those words.

Again, spanish helped me.

Probably =

Based on prudent reason - That can be proved - Said when there's good reasons to believe it will happen or will be verifiable.

Possible =

That can be or happen - that can be executed - available media to do something

Possible implies that exist the possibility, let's say 1%.

Probably implies that based on probability the chances to happen are good, let´s say above 50%.

Remember that Probable, probability, are math terms in statistics. Possibility is not used because it works even against all odds. Just having the minimal chance, something is possible. But is probably not going to work, because the chances are too low.

Answer (score -1):

I think the difference between *probably* and *possibly* is somewhat related to *may* and *can*. E.g.

- Probably enough to make you laugh = may or may not be enough, not very sure about it, neither does it matter very much
- Possibly enough to make you sick = can be enough; warns of the *ability* (e.g. of a virus) to make you sick, and it's important to know

Comment: As you write it, possibly would have a stronger meaning that propably, but isn't it the other way around?

Comment: @Eldros: I think in many contexts they both bear the same meaning of some probability in a mathematical sense, but sometimes "possibly" also has some "ability" flavor in it.

Comment: I disagree with your analysis. For me "probably" is certainly more likely than "possibly", and neither says very much about the importance of the question.

Comment: @Colin Fine: I'm not saying which one is more likely to happen, but indication of ability (possibly) and indication of a chance (probably). E.g. just found this phrase on the 'Net: "It's not only possible, it's probable" in a sense that not only someone can do it in principle, but also is likely to do it.

Comment: This isn't right.  "Probable" means the thing is likely to happen.  If I say something is "probably enough to make you laugh" it means that I think it's likely, though perhaps not guaranteed.  And neither "probable" nor "possible" carries an implication of whether the thing is important or not.

Comment: @Henry: so if *probably* means "it's likely, though perhaps not guaranteed", then what is *possibly* exactly, if there is any difference of course?

Comment: @Henry: also on the importance: if you say "probably enough to make you sick" doesn't emphasize the ability of the virus but rather a game of chance, compared to "possibly enough to make you sick"

Comment: @mojuba: "Possibly" means that there is some chance (depending on context, it might mean "any chance, even a trivial one", or it might mean "a more than trivial chance"), but it's always consistent with a less than 50% chance, while "probably" implies a more than 50% chance.

Comment: @mojuba: Regarding importance, "possibly enough to make you sick" is expressing that being sick is theoretically possible (though perhaps very unlikely); it's certainly consistent with it not being important: "Can this chemical make me sick" "Well, it's possible, but only if you accidentally eat a huge amount."  By contrast "probably" means we've already settled that it *could* happen, and we're worrying about whether it *will* happen.  "Probably enough to make you sick" doesn't emphasize the theoretical ability, it emphasizes that it's a serious likelihood.

Comment: @Henry: if we forget about the importance/seriousness for a moment, I agree with this: "Probably ... doesn't emphasize the theoretical ability, it emphasizes that it's a serious likelihood" and I think it supports my original thesis on *may* vs. *can*. "Probably" may happen, no matter how serious the consequences, and "possibly" can happen because of the active potential, like in the example with chemicals, viruses etc.