# Is "should" ever used as past tense of "shall"?

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs

Looking at the dictionary, I read that *should* has origin as past tense of *shall*.

> ORIGIN Old English *sceolde*: past of *shall*.

In  the modern English, is *should* ever used as past tense of *shall*?

Comment: `shall` is not a verb, it's an auxiliary. How can it even have a past tense?

Comment: @Noldorin: Modal verbs have present and past tenses.  "I *will* go tomorrow", but "Last week I said that I *would* go the next day".

Comment: @Kosmonaut: They're pseudo-tenses, not real tenses.

Comment: @Noldorin: I'm not familiar with the concept of a "pseudo-tense".

Comment: @Kosmonaut: The word *behaves* like its another word in a different tense, but it is not technically one.

Comment: @Noldorin: It is technically not a tense according to what criteria?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**should** is the preterite form of the modal verb whose present form is **shall**. As such, *should* can be (and is still) used in the past tense, in places where *shall* would be used in the present tense.

Two examples:

- *“It is time, we shall proceed”* can be reported as *“he said it was time, we should proceed”*.
- *“I think it shall be okay”* and *“I thought it should be okay”*

Other modal verbs that follow the same pattern are **will/would**, **may/might** and **can/could**.

Comment: Right. I think the only thing that might make it hard (for an American) to think of *should* as the past tense of *shall* would be the fact that Americans don't really ever use the word *shall* at all.  So we wouldn't generally be converting it to past tense either.  But I imagine that people still actively do this in the UK.

Comment: You don't use *shall* in oral language, but it's still used in normative, legislative, judicial and lots of other written styles. Things like “Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion” (dated, I admit), or “Any balance to the credit of the designated beneficiary shall be ...” (excerpt from recent IRS document) or others

Comment: I use “shall” orally if infrequently.

Comment: Shall we go? Americans do use shall. Shall I open the window?

Answer (score 0):

> should is the preterite form of the
>   modal verb whose present form is
>   shall. As such, should can be (and is
>   still) used in the past tense, in
>   places where shall would be used in
>   the present tense.
>
> Two examples:
>
> “It is time, we shall proceed” can be
>   reported as “he said it was time, we
>   should proceed”. “I think it shall be
>   okay” and “I thought it should be
>   okay” Other modal verbs that follow
>   the same pattern are will/would,
>   may/might and can/could.

Giving examples of reported speech doesn't illustrate that modal verbs have tense. The backshift to the *Historical past tense forms*, of modals, that only sometimes occurs doesn't express a true tense shift. It only tells those in our speaking/writing audience, that by making this replacement, that we are not directly quoting what the original speaker said.

If this was actually a true shift in tense, we wouldn't be able to quote someone directly because that important tense/time shift wouldn't show up and there would be considerable misunderstanding.

Let's look at an example:

Charles: I need some paper.

Brett: What did Charles say?

Jane: He said that he needed some paper.

When Jane used 'needed', the past tense form of 'need', she wasn't saying that the need has disappeared, that the need has been met, that Charles no longer needs paper. Using the past tense FORM is just a signal, not the actual shift that we see when an event is actually finished.

Jane: He said that he needed some paper but he got some from Art, so he doesn't need any now.

Noldorin is at least partially correct. Modals are a special class of verbs which carry various modal meanings into sentences.

Comment: I don't understand your argument about real versus fake tense shifting. It looks exactly the same to me. That's not to say that modal "tenses" have the same distinctions as for normal verbs. Rather, this is not a clear or salient argument.

Answer (score -1):

**Should** is the past form of 'shall'. It is used in modern English.

I said 'I *shall* go'.

I said that I *should* go.

can- *could* (past), will- *would* (past), may- *might* (past)

present- He *can* read.

past-He *could* read (at the age of four).

He said 'I *will* go'.

He said that he *would* go.