# “May” vs. “might”

Tags: word-choice, differences

What’s the difference between these sentences:

1. I thought you **might** be interested in looking at this event.
2. I thought you **may** be interested in looking at this event.

Comment: Am I missing something? These sentences are identical.

Comment: I am voting to close, this seems to be a trolling question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Theoretically, "may" implies permission, whereas "might" implies that its physically possible.

In practice most people don't know there's supposed to be a distinction. They are typically used interchangeably.

Comment: Ok. I think you've convinced me (and convinced me this is a dup.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the may/might distinction is really in the tense:

1. I **thought** you **might** enjoy this event. ***(past tense)***
2. I **think** you **may** enjoy this event. ***(present tense)***

NOTE:  I changed the end of the sentences for clarity.

Comment: This is covered in far greater depth in the [Are “might” and “should” past tenses of “may” and “shall”, respectively?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3785/are-might-and-should-past-tenses-of-may-and-shall-respectively) thread. I've upvoted psmears's answer there.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I read that entire thread and think that question comes from a completely different perspective.  That one discusses 'may'/'might' as the primary verb in the sentence and whether or not 'might' is the past tense (or completed) form of the word 'may'.  This question is more about choosing between 'may'/'might' in a clause (which, in both cases is forward-looking).